# What's the default value of the charset attribute of a script tag?

Tags: html, character-encoding

Say I have a script like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js">`

I've seen some sources online that claim that if the `charset` attribute is omitted, it defaults to ISO-8859-1.  I've seen others that claim it assumes the same encoding as the HTML page that contains the script tag.  What's the truth?

I need to know because my JavaScript file contains literal strings that will be inserted into the HTML, and which include non-ASCII characters like the Euro symbol (€).  I realize that adding a charset attribute or just HTML encoding these characters should solve my problem, but I'd still like to understand the default behavior.

EDIT: To clarify one point, I need to know not just what the standards say, but how browsers actually act.  The behavior described here: http://joconner.com/2008/09/javascript-file-encoding/ seems to suggest that browsers *don't* always assume ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I would expect the default behaviour to be dependent on your **server** rather than upon the charset defined in any "enclosing" content. I don't know this for sure though, so am posting as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: IIRC, browsers default to "The encoding of the page that script appears in, sometimes even if the charset says otherwise". I don't have an authoritative source though, so I'm hesitant to put this as an answer..

Comment: @Ben Poole: When you say it's dependent on the server, do you mean on the HTTP headers the server sends, or something else?  I mean, it's ultimately the web browser that has to figure out how to read the script, right?

Comment: HTTP headers yes; most servers have a default configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The w3c has a standard way for a browser to determine the char encoding, you can read about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#spec-char-encoding

> To sum up, conforming user agents must
> observe the following priorities when
> determining a document's character
> encoding (from highest priority to
> lowest):
>
> 1. An HTTP "charset" parameter in a "Content-Type" field.
> 2. A META declaration with "http-equiv" set to "Content-Type" and a value set for "charset".
> 3. The charset attribute set on an element that designates an external resource.
>
> In addition to this
> list of priorities, the user agent may
> use heuristics and user settings. For
> example, many user agents use a
> heuristic to distinguish the various
> encodings used for Japanese text.
> Also, user agents typically have a
> user-definable, local default
> character encoding which they apply in
> the absence of other indicators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm a little confused by this though. Is this saying the HTTP charset parameter of the HTML page will override the charset attribute of the script element?  If so, the charset attribute doesn't seem very useful.  Or maybe it's only the HTTP headers of script call itself that take precedence over its charset attribute.

Comment: @Tim: It is only the response headers for the script file itself that it refers to.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  What I take from this is I need to make sure a charset is set either in the HTTP headers of the script or with the charset attribute of the script element, otherwise all bets are off.  I'm accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_charset.asp) the value is ISO-8859-1 and this is supported across all major browsers.

According to the [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7.1):

> When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP. Data in character sets other than "ISO-8859-1" or its subsets MUST be labeled with an appropriate charset value. See section [3.4.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.4.1) for compatibility problems.

So anything that doesn't conform to this does not technically follow the HTTP 1.1 specification.

Comment: That link is w3schools which so far as I know is not affiliated with the W3C (despite the similar name).

Comment: It may nevertheless be true that that's the correct behavior according to the W3C standard, but this description seems to suggest that behavior isn't always followed: http://joconner.com/2008/09/javascript-file-encoding/

Comment: I believe the HTTP specification is referring to the charset parameter in the HTTP headers, not the charset attribute of a script tag.

Comment: I also note this from the W3C's HTML4 recommendation (linked from Martin Jespersen's answer) `The HTTP protocol ([RFC2616], section 3.7.1) mentions ISO-8859-1 as a default character encoding when the "charset" parameter is absent from the "Content-Type" header field. In practice, this recommendation has proved useless because some servers don't allow a "charset" parameter to be sent, and others may not be configured to send the parameter. Therefore, user agents must not assume any default value for the "charset" parameter.`

Comment: Please see [www.w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com) before you trust their site.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML5** *4.11.1 The script element*:

> If the script element has a charset attribute, then let the script block's character encoding for this script element be the result of getting an encoding from the value of the charset attribute.
>
> Otherwise, let the script block's fallback character encoding for this script element be the same as the encoding of the document itself.

The quote links to the DOM `document` element, which has an `encoding` property.

TODO: find how the encoding of that object is determined from the standards.

Comment: This might only apply to JavaScript embedded in an HTML document. If the script tag refers to JavaScript in an external file, it may be different. For example, RFC4329 specifies that external JS files fallback to UTF-8: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4329#page-5

Answer (score 0):

HTML encoding strings and passing them into javascript variables can cause problems, specially if you use hex codes as js I'm told prefers octal.

If you can work in utf-8 as the charset of your web pages then js works with these just fine. I use this a lot and there has never been a need to define a charset for the included script files.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case I can't control the charset of the HTML pages themselves, as that's controlled by our client.  I'm just adding scripts.  And in fact they use different encodings on different pages of their site.